# How to get array from firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a react project for download movies . In this project user can like to movie and add to watchlist. I need to get array of like and store it on browser local storage . I need to know how to get array from firestore .

This is path of array I need to get.

> users  > {user id} > likes

This is what I tried.

```
firebase
   .firestore()
   .collection("users")
   .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
   .collection("likes")
   .get()
   .then((likes) => {
       console.log(likes)
             });
```

[image: This is my data structure]

Answer (score 1):

`.collection("likes")` `likes` is a field not a collection so to get `likes` field you have to read whole document.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
         firebase
   .firestore()
   .collection("users")
   .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
   .get()
   .then((user_doc) => {
       console.log(user_doc.data())
    });
```